# Use Pandas or SQL to calculate Revenue based on subscription duration?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to calculate some monthly business indicators based on revenue using a csv that has the following fields: client ID, start of subscription, subscription duration and subscription value.

Since I'll need to make comparisons on past months(if the revenue for a specific client has decresed, for example), my initial idea was to create new columns for each month and based on those columns, use panda to find the values and store them on a new table for these indicators.

Do you guys think that this is the best way to go or it would be best to try and use SQL to obtain these metrics?

Sorry if the question is not clear, cloudn't find a way to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sure if I perfectly understood your problem, but it looks that you need a way to iteract between the current and a past date of a client value.

see if this code can help you:

```py
# example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[1,2,3,1,2,3],
                   'client':['c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2'],
                   'value':[123, 234, 123, 456, 345, 678]})
# Set index to access items faster
df.set_index(['client', 'date'], inplace=True)

# iteract each item
delta = []
for client in df.index.levels[0]:
    for date in df.index.levels[1]:
        # if the item do not exist on index, nothing happens
        try:
            current = df.loc[client].loc[date]['value']
            # if there isnt past date, delta is zero, but uou can change it
            try:
                before = df.loc[client].loc[date-1]['value']
                delta.append(current - before)
            except:
                delta.append(0)
        except:
            pass

df['delta'] = delta
df
```